# javascript toggle menu close on click

Tags: javascript, toggle, nav

I am using this bit of javascript code for a responsive menu - all I need it to do is to close (not hide) the toggle menu on click. I don't understand javascript at all, so I was hoping for the exact code I need to replace. I haven't been able to figure it out from looking at other similar posts on here. Thanks.

```
  $ (document).ready(function(){
    $('nav a.mobile_menu').on('click', function() {
        var currentNAvHeight = $('nav').height();
        if( currentNAvHeight < 5){
            var newNavHeight = $('nav > ul').height() + 15;
            $('nav').animate({'height': newNavHeight + 'px'}, 750);
        }else {
            $('nav').animate({'height':'0px'}, 750, function () {
            $(this).removeAttr('style');
            });
        }
    });
    $(window).resize(function(){
        if ( $(this).width() > 625) {
            $('nav').removeAttr('style');
        }
    });
  });
```

Comment: replace the animate in the else branch with code to close the menu, something like `$('nav').css("display", "none")`...

Comment: Hiya, I tried swapping    $('nav').animate({'height':'0px'}, 750, function ()  for what you suggested but saw an error... what bit exactly are you suggesting I change?